# vlookup varying index reference

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with the following vlookup equations with index reference.

I am trying to make the index reference (for my case testdiff) to increase by a value from 2 onwards. From what I have tested, it did not increased at all even with the statement of testdiff = testdiff+1

```
Dim colnum As Integer, testdiff As Integer

For colnum = 2 To 14

    testdiff = 2

    Sheets("Sheets1").Cells(8, colnum ).Formula = "=iferror(vlookup(" & Sheets("Sheets1").Cells(8, 2).Address(False, True) & ",'Sheet2'!" & Range("A:E").Address & "," & testdiff & ",False), ""NA"")"

    testdiff = testdiff + 1

Next colnum
```

Comment: If you are trying to write that formula into row 8, columns B to N with an incrementing *col_index_num* parameter starting at *2* then you are going to need a wider *table_array* parameter than A:E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testdiff is always going to be 2 for the formula because it is inside the loop. If you put that outside the loop (before the for statement) it will work until colnum = 14 then testdiff will be 6 and your formula only accounts for 5 columns (A:E) so it will error here If you want all columns A:E then you need to change

```
testdiff = 2
```

to

```
testdiff = 1
```

and still have it before the For loop

Modified code:

```
Dim colnum As long, testdiff As long
testdiff = 2
For colnum = 2 To 14
    Sheets("Sheets1").Cells(8, colnum).Formula = "=iferror(vlookup(" & Sheets("Sheets1").Cells(8, 2).Address(False, True) & ",'Sheet2'!" & Range("A:N").Address & "," & testdiff & ",False), ""NA"")"
    testdiff = testdiff + 1
Next colnum
```

Note, don't use Integer in VBA, use long.

Comment: I have tried it, the formula is still referencing to testdiff = 1 on subsequent columns even if I set it outside the loop. By the way, I made a mistake at the colnum, it should be from 2 to 14

Comment: OK, You still have the problem where testdiff = 2 is inside the loop, that means that each time the loop iterates it will increase it by 1 then at the start of the loop set it back to 2. Also putting the colnum loop up doesn't help you because you have this: & Range("A:E").Address & 5 columns, as soon as testdiff gets to 6 it will error. It needs to be A:N. See my updated answer for modified code

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you were incrementing the *testdiff* variable with `testdiff = testdiff + 1` but then resetting it to *2* with `testdiff = 2` on the next cycle of the loop. `testdiff = 2` needs to be outside (above) the loop.

I would recommend blocking the formula into all 13 cells at once.

```
   Sheets("Sheets1").Cells(8, 2).resize(1, 13).Formula = _
      "=iferror(vlookup(" & Sheets("Sheets1").Cells(8, 2).Address(False, True) & ",'Sheet2'!$A:B, column(B:B), False), ""NA"")"
```

Note that `COLUMN(B:B)` will increment  as *2, 3, 4, etc* as it is filled right.

Comment: This solution is much better, always try to avoid loops if you can (especially when playing around with resource costly vlookups)